# Gmail Integration how to add a new contact?

Tags: lightning, gmail

i need the buttom "add contact"[image]

i
I'm not seeing the button

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000319720&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: is the same issue , but i couldn't solve it

Comment: Have you tried steps mentioned in above article?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to fix it:

1. Go to Setup | Gmail Integration and Sync
2. Expand the Gmail Integration Section
3. Look in the Email Application Publisher Layouts section and ensure you have at least one layout defined.
4. If you don't have a layout defined, create one using the "New" button in that section.  Add any desired actions to the quick actions panel
5. Once you've saved/edited your layout, click the "Publisher Layout Assignment" button and ensure every profile has an assigned layout.
6. Save all your changes and reload your Gmail page.

[image: Gmail Integration - Email Application Publisher Layouts]